# Problems with Adblock detecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, adblock

I'm working on a basic Adblock detection script, and I've come up with something that seems like it *should* work. Upon creating an element on the page with the ID of `#adblock_detection_image` in Chrome with Adblock Plus, running `$('#adblock_detection_image').css('display')` gives me the value `none` and running `$('#adblock_detection_image').css('visibility')` gives me the value `hidden`. When running these on a browser with no Adblocker, I get `inline` and `visible` instead, as one might expect.

Finding this, I went ahead and attempted to craft a solution. The issue - however - is that the code that should trigger when an adblocker is detected simple doesn't trigger. The code snippet is shown below.

```
function isUsingAdblocker(classOfAd)
{
    if(parseInt($(classOfAd).css('height')) <= 0)
{
            return true;
}
    else
{
            $('body').append('<img id="adblock_detection_image" src="/textlink-ads-banner-advert-service.jpg" style="width: 0; height: 10px;  position: relative; top: -1000px; left: -1000px;"/>');
    if($('#adblock_detection_image').css('display') != 'inline')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if($('#adblock_detection_image').css('visibility') != 'visible')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(isUsingAdblocker('#Ad-One')){
        $('#Ad-One').html('<em>Please</em> disable your ad-blocking software to help support this website.<br/><span>(It\'s our primary source of income!)');
        $('#Ad-One').css('height', '90px');
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is `adClass` defined? When looking at your page its `undefined`

Comment: @john_doe Whoops! Removed the variable in recent modifications and forgot to change it in the document.ready. Fixed now, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps , an adblocker remove the elemet contained the ads , in there "#Ad-one",so when you access the css of this element by jq ,in reality you access to an unavilable element was removed from html source earlier.isnt it true?

Comment: @msk Wrong an AdBlocker is a CSS file which is added to each page, this CSS file contains a lot of listed ad selectors, and normally all of these ad element's are set to `display: none !important;`

Comment: i guess it only , so you can be trust :D tanx for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Adblock searches for elements which contain words like ad or german "werbung" or other words, that are often used for ads. You should give your elements a different name which doesn't contain that words. Had same problem at my first website, where I named a div "left_ad".

Comment: I'm using Adsense so Adblock always detects it. The code snippet I show in the OP should sucessfully get Adblocks attention and hence I get 'none' when trying `$('#adblock_detection_image').css('display')` in the console. When executing the OP snippet on the page's load though - it just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @DRP96 Wrong an AdBlocker is a CSS file which is added to each page, this CSS file contains a lot of listed ad selectors, and normally all of these ad element's are set to `display: none !important;`

Comment: @micha, Yes I know that. What I said was just meant symbolic.