# Javascript Alert Alternate with Jquery Message

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, adblock

I am just a learner and don't have clue about javascript and jquery. What I want to ad an adblock detector script. What I found is this piece of code which gives a nasty alert message. What I want is to give an ajaxed message just not a message popping out of screen.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function _enabled() {
    alert('Hey Dude!!! You are using Adblock on this site? Please disable Adblock or Any other plugin blocking ads. Its the only way we cover the cost of the Servers and Website. Click OK to continue what you were doing');
}
function _disabled() {
    alert('not detected');
}
var _abdDetectedFnc = '_enabled';
var _abdNotDetectedFnc = 'disabled';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.adblockdetector.com/script.php"></script>
```

**Replacing this code can you please help me with an alternate to this code?**

```
{
        alert('Hey Dude!!! You are using Adblock on this site? Please disable Adblock or Any other plugin blocking ads. Its the only way we cover the cost of the Servers and Website. Click OK to continue what you were doing');
    }
```

I came along finding some solutions about getting it with jquery or jquery-ui but don't have the knowledge of what to put here and replacing the code. I tried code example from http://m0006.gamecopyworld.com/games/gcw_notice.shtml which gives a nice friendly Adblock Detect message. But it wasn't working at all. Only this Alert Message is working on my website.

Comment: What does Ajax have to do with showing an error message? Did you want the message to be from a remote call to your server?

Comment: I told in the start, I am just a learner or you can say beginner. Sorry I used Ajaxed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a very quick alternative, that looks a bit nicer you can use a jQuery-ui dialog (as Ricky Baby said)

You will also need to include the jQuery and jQuery-ui libraries in your page. 
These can be downloaded from http://jquery.com/download/ and http://jqueryui.com/download/, if you haven't got them already.

You can change the "Hey dude ...... etc" text to what ever you like

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body style='height: 100%;'>
<script type="text/javascript">
function _enabled() 
{
    var html = "<div>Adbloc detected</div>";

    var diag = $(html).dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        close: function() { $(this).empty().remove(); },
        buttons: 
        {
            "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    });
}
function _disabled() 
{
    var html = "<div>Adbloc NOT detected</div>";

    var diag = $(html).dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        close: function() { $(this).empty().remove(); },
        buttons: 
        {
            "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    });
}
var _abdDetectedFnc = '_enabled';
var _abdNotDetectedFnc = '_disabled';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.adblockdetector.com/script.php"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively you could just put a message at the bottom of the screen if you didn't want a pop up at all

```
<div id='adBlockDetected' style='position: fixed; bottom: 20px; left: 0px; width: 100%; display: none;' >Hey dide .... etc </div>
```

Then in the _enabled() function

```
$("#adBlockDetected").css({display: "block" });
```

Comment: Tried it but still its not working at all. Only alert () appears on the screen.

Comment: Alternate code is working, can you please guide how to do it like in overlay and shadow. Means the user may click ok to the message and then start using the website

Comment: I've been having a play with the code and found a bug, the var _abdNotDetectedFnc = 'disabled'; needs an underscore before the word disabled otherwise it will error when AdBloc is not present.

Comment: If you want the user to have to acknowledge the message, then your best option is the jQuery dialog route. I'll try to get that workign and post the complete code - brb.

Comment: Edited original post with full working example as a stand alone HTML page

Comment: It works very fine but if the user has disabled adblock it will again give a message everytime that "Adbloc NOT Detected"

Comment: Edited the code which is working fine so far, please check it at your end

Comment: Hi YoPakistan - the example code displayed the dialog on both enabled and disabled on purpose. If the code is working is working could you mark it as "Answered" to help any others with a similar query.

Answer (score 2):

See this question:

[Problems with Adblock detecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861750/problems-with-adblock-detecting?rq=1)

at the bottom, he sets his message to display in a div ( which he calls #Ad-One ) by setting the html attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use JQuery-ui there is the dialog option to make the message box more pretty see: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

However you are also getting your terms mixed up - AJAX - is a "brand" name for requesting data from the remote sever using the XMLHTTP object and related techniques.

Comment: Been already there @Ricky but I don't understand that stuff currently, i am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is "pretty" alerts, jQuery UI is a bit of an overkill. I'd go with something like Apprise: http://thrivingkings.com/read/Apprise-v2-The-new-and-improved-attractive-alert-alternative-for-jQuery

Using nothing but the default settings:

```
<!-- added to head -->
<link href="path_to_css/apprise-v2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="path_to_jquery"></script>
<script src="path_to_scripts/apprise-v2.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function(){
        Apprise('hi there');
    });

</script>
```

gets you a pretty slick alert message:

[image]

Of course, I'm also curious as to what you're trying to achieve here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.adblockdetector.com/script.php"></script>
```

Unless that PHP page is actually a JavaScript file, you can't do that. The `src` attribute needs to point to a valid and addressable JavaScript file.

Comment: @Tieson `<script src="domain/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="domain/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="domain/apprise-v2.min.css"></script>
<script src="domain/apprise-v2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function _enabled() {
    Apprise('Disable Adblock');
}
function _disabled() {
    alert('not detected');
}
var _abdDetectedFnc = '_enabled';
var _abdNotDetectedFnc = 'disabled';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.yopakistan.com/adblock_detector.js"></script>`Now where is the issue?